# CountIF true on last occurence for list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a list of people who have participated in a two part assessment, & want to track total analytics of how many people have passed the assessment vs how many have failed.

My worksheet looks something like this

| Date | StudentID | Part 1 or 2? | Pass? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | George | 1 | True |
| 01/01/2022 | Brandon | 1 | True |
| 01/01/2022 | Daniel | 1 | False |
| 01/01/2022 | Tahlia | 1 | True |
| 01/01/2022 | Jane | 1 | True |
| 02/01/2022 | George | 2 | True |
| 02/01/2022 | Brandon | 2 | False |
| 02/01/2022 | Tahlia | 2 | True |
| 02/01/2022 | Jane | 2 | True |

In this case, we know that 3 people passed and 2 others failed the assessment.

I know I can find the last entry for each student and check if they passed or failed individually using

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($B:$B="George"),$D:$D)
```

but that would use an extra column & take up unnecessary space. (I know I can hide columns) What I would like to do is lookup the users who did pass and count them.

So... my question is, how can I combine `=CountIF()` with `=Lookup()` to count how many students have passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the `UNIQUE` function, you could use the following formula to get the number of `FALSE` for each individual student:

```
=COUNTIFS(Pass?,FALSE,StudentID,UNIQUE(StudentID))
'i.e. {0;1;1;0;0}
```

To get the ones that passed, use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS(Pass?,FALSE,StudentID,UNIQUE(StudentID))=0))
'i.e. =SUMPRODUCT(--({0;1;1;0;0}=0)) => 3
```

---

Update: explainer formula

In this formula `UNIQUE(StudentID)` is getting you an array with the unique students in order of appearance:
`{"George";"Brandon";"Daniel";"Tahlia";"Jane"}`

Next, `COUNTIFS(Pass?,FALSE,StudentID,UNIQUE(StudentID)` gets us the count of `FALSE` for each individual student, also as an array: `{0;1;1;0;0}`. I.e. Zero `FALSE` for "George", "Tahlia" and "Jane", 1 `FALSE` for "Brandon" and "Daniel".

Finally, we simply would have wanted to do a `COUNTIFS` to count all zeros. However, the results are in an array, and `COUNTIF(S)` does not work with an array. This is why we use `SUMPRODUCT` with the "double-negative" (double unary) operation. This operation coerces `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`, so we are getting `--({0;1;1;0;0}=0)` => `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}` => `{1,0,0,1,1}`. Now, `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies and sums this final array, leading to 3.

(N.B. In the current example, the final array is simply the inverse of the input array. This is so, because no student had more than one `FALSE`. But if a student had `FALSE` twice, the final array would not be different.)

Comment: This works just how I needed it too. Oddly it adds an 1 extra even if everyone failed, it still says 1 passed, fixed with -1 on the end of the formula for now. I tried to reverse engineer your formula to work out how it works but couldn't figure out why that was occuring. Oh well, thank you dearly.

Comment: Added some explanation on what the formula does. You say; "Oddly it adds an 1 extra even if everyone failed, it still says 1 passed". This shouldn't be possible. If every student has at least 1 `FALSE`, the result of this formula should definitely be 0, not 1. You might be getting 1, because your column with students contains empty rows. If so, the formula will also be counting `FALSE` for a unique empty value (""), and that count will indeed be 1.

Comment: Apologies. Last sentence of my prev comment is wrong. Should be: "If so, the formula will also be counting FALSE for a unique student "0", and that count will indeed be `0` (no FALSE), leading to one `1` in the final array, as if this "student" passed."

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.
When testing for passed, ```=0``` works great.
Interestingly if testing for fail ```=1``` will not count them if they've failed twice as we're getting 2 instead of 1. (Shouldn't occur but good to have a failsafe)
Using ```>0``` has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

If the reality of your context is that you only need to count people who have passed stage 2 then you could use the formula in C12 below

[image]

```
=SUM(--((C2:C10)*(D2:D10)=2))
```

(this would have to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you're using Excel 2019 or earlier)

Comment: If this is the case, there's no need for an array formula. Just use: `=COUNTIFS(C2:C10,2,D2:D10,TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, this solves most of my problem though part 1 is still important for my sheet.

Occasionally someone takes their part 2 course with another trainer however & from my end, they've still passed their part 1. I don't want to sum the total passes, just how many unique students have passed & ignore them completely if they failed the second part. (Hope that makes sense)